# persisting a new user to the db

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am aware of the FOSuserbundle availability but in order to help learn symfony2 I decided to try to create everything from scratch by using the book/cookbook.

After following the [cookbooks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) tutorials for security I am having trouble working out how to persist a new user to the database.  I have everything else working fine, logins, firewall security domains, password encryption etc

When I try to add a user I get the following error:

> Neither the property "roles" nor one of the methods "addRol()"/"removeRol()", "addRole()"/"removeRole()", "setRoles()", "roles()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Ampisoft\Bundle\etrackBundle\Entity\users"

I've noticed that the `users()` class doesn't have a setRoles method, but I'm unsure how to add one as it needs to use an array object(?).  the other thing confusing me is that the error highlights no `addRole()` (and not `addRoles` method, even though the member is `roles`.

my code is as follows:

**users entity class** (its got quite bit so these is just the sections I think are important

```
class users implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    // ......

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="roles", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $roles;


    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

   /**
     * Add roles
     *
     * @param \Ampisoft\Bundle\etrackBundle\Entity\roles $roles
     * @return users
     */
    public function addRoles(roles $roles)
    {
        $this->roles[] = $roles;

        return $this;
    }
    // ......
}
```

**roles entity class** (again, related sections)

```
class roles implements RoleInterface
{
    // .........

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="users", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

   /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param \Ampisoft\Bundle\etrackBundle\Entity\users $user
     * @return roles
     */
    public function addUser(users $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }
    // .........
}
```

**controller**

```
public function admin_new_userAction()
{
    $user = new users();
    $form = $this->createForm(new usersType(), $user);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // if form is posted
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);

        $user->setSalt(md5(time()));

        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user); //get encoder for hashing pwd later
        $tempPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
        $user->setPassword($tempPassword);

        // flush to db
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_users'));

    }

    // BUILD FORM
    return $this->render('etBundle:Admin:new_user.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**the usersType class** (I plan to use this for editing users as well hense the listener)

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $user = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // check if the User object is "new"
        if (!$user || null === $user->getId()) {
            $form->add('username', 'text');
            $form->add('firstname', 'text');
            $form->add('lastname', 'text');
            $form->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
                'required' => false,
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
            ));
            $form->add('email', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'email',
                'invalid_message' => 'The email address fields must match.',
                'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'email-field')),
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Email'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Email'),
            ));
            $form->add('email', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'email',
                'invalid_message' => 'The email address fields must match.',
                'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'email-field')),
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Email'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Email'),
            ));
            $form->add('lastLogged', 'hidden');
            $form->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'etBundle:roles',
                'property' => 'name',
            ));

        } else {
            $form->add('id', 'hidden');
            $form->add('username', 'text');
            $form->add('firstname', 'text');
            $form->add('lastname', 'text');
            $form->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
                'required' => false,
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
            ));
            $form->add('email', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'email',
                'invalid_message' => 'The email address fields must match.',
                'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'email-field')),
                'required' => true,
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Email'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Email'),
            ));

        }

    });
```

I see there is an `addUser` method in the `roles()` class but Im unsure on how to use it. I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

** ***update*** 1**

I tried inserting the suggested setRoles() method above and now Im recieving the following
`error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\Dropbox\xampp\htdocs\etrack3\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.‌​php on line 555 and defined`

** ***update*** 2**
fixed this problem: realised that I had a manytomany/manytomany relationship between my Users/Roles entities.  Changed to manyToOne/OneToMany and all is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `class users` is missing its constructor, which initializes the `$roles` property to an `ArrayCollection` instance. I'd also advise against your using the `$this->users[]` notation, in favour of treating these properties as what they really are:

```
$this->users->add($user);
```

As for the error you're getting, that's down to how Doctrine loads its entities. The error shows what doctrine looks for in an entity class, in order to set the properties: either the `roles` property should be public, or you need a method with a name that looks like `set<ucfirst-name-of-table-field>`, or a slow magic getter/setter interface.

As far as the `setRoles` and `setUsers` methods are concerned, that's a simple matter:

```
public function setRoles($roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
    return $this;
}
```

With the option of adding a type-hint:

```
public function setRoles( ArrayCollection $roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
    return $this;
}
```

Some other issues I'd like to mention:

Coding standards are important, check the most commonly adopted standards [here](http://www.php-fig.org). Doctrine, Symfony2, ZendFW2, ... all the major players subscribe to these standards, and so should you. A class name, for example starts with an upper-case character, so `class users` should become `class Users` etc...
I'd also advise against implementing the `Serializable` interface on doctrine entities, especially if you make `users` Serializable, which might contain `Roles` instances, which does not implement `Serializable`.

Comment: many thanks for the reply.  I do have a `__construct()`, I just didnt show it as I was trying to cut down the page content.  I have made the changes to class names as suggested.  It was something I found out after I started and had been too lazy to fix!! done now.  Ill give your suggestion a try for the issue then report back